# Use the same object animator property (translationx) twice on one object at the same time

Tags: android, class, objectanimator, animatorset

I have spent the entire day trying to figure this out. I have tried a plethora of code combinations but none of them want to work. Well technically they do work but not the way I'm wanting it to. If I add translationY property it works. I'm basically wanting run 2 animations, both translationx, on a single object at the same time. The object should go from left to right for the entire width of the screen and be moving back and forth a short distance at the same time. So the main question is, is it possible to achieve this or is it not possible to use the same property with an AnimatorSet at the same time?

here is the current code I'm working with:

```
private void _ballLevel20Animation () {
    move1.cancel();
    int center = (board.getMeasuredWidth() / 2);
    int lr = board.getMeasuredWidth();
    final float left = Float.valueOf(100 - center);
    final float right = Float.valueOf(center - 100);
    int center1 = (board.getMeasuredWidth() / 6);
    final float left1 = Float.valueOf(100 - center);
    final float right1 = Float.valueOf(center - 100);
    move1.setTarget(ball);
    move1.setPropertyName("translationX");
    move1.setFloatValues(left, right);
    move1.setRepeatCount(ObjectAnimator.INFINITE);
    move1.setDuration((int)(ball_duration_increa));
    move1.setRepeatMode(ValueAnimator.REVERSE);
    bounce_ani.setTarget(ball);
    bounce_ani.setPropertyName("translationX");
    bounce_ani.setFloatValues((float)(SketchwareUtil.getDip(getApplicationContext(), (int)(-20))), (float)(SketchwareUtil.getDip(getApplicationContext(), (int)(20))));
    bounce_ani.setRepeatCount(ObjectAnimator.INFINITE);
    bounce_ani.setDuration((int)(ball_duration_increa / 6));
    bounce_ani.setRepeatMode(ValueAnimator.REVERSE);
    AnimatorSet animatorSet = new AnimatorSet();

    animatorSet.play(bounce_ani).with(move1);

    animatorSet.start();
    /*bounce_ani.setFloatValues(right1, left1);*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding an animation listener to the animation. In the listener, there is onAnimationEnd() which gets called when the animation is done. Here, you may call succeeding animations such that they appear that they are chained.

[Android Guide on Animation - Animation Listeners](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation#listeners)

Comment: The code I have if I change the property of one of them to something besides translation X it works but there seems to be a problem that I can't play the same properties at the same time on one object. If I change one to translation why in the other one translation X it will work. Is there any special class that would allow me to run to object animators that are the same at the same? I appreciate your response thank you.